# pgadmin 4 3.1 retiling data output panel

Tags: pgadmin-4

In the Query Tool, when trying to raise or lower the border between Query Sql Editor and Data Output Panel it is very common that when you move the mouse over the Data Output panel's header it  changes the vertical - horizontal arrow icon  to a cross arrow changing Data Output panel from its default tiling to floating

What should I do to return the Data Output panel to its initial tiling mode?

In addition, Data Output panel once in floating window stops showing queries's  results, it only shows the messages, I suppose it's 3.1's bug.

My solution so far is to save the query, close it and reopen it to recover its tiling mode

Cursor's disappearance problems have not been corrected in full

What is the best free competitor of pgadmin 4?

Comment: A great free competitor is DBeaver Community edition.  I love Postgres, but sadly PgAdmin 4 has sadly not measured up to expectations.

Comment: Now the question even more actual as pgAdmin of modern versions remembers layout for the query tool, and reopening does not help any more :)

Comment: Yes, this is a very annoying feature, can't help agreeing with you!

Comment: Has anyone discovered how to get the rest of pgAdmin back if you inadvertently make a panel full size? I've just restarted 3 times due to inadvertent clicks. This is an amazingly poor UX.

Answer (score 234):

In the pgadmin browser, click on the `File` menu and select `reset layout`.

Yes, will get all kinds of warnings, but the query tool returns to being useful.

Comment: Warnings are to remind users of some things like: you'll lose your existing (executed) scripts on the current panel, and so on. Should be careful as well.

Comment: Thank you for this. Was frustrated when this happened.

Comment: This deletes all your open files. What a horrible solution just to re-dock a single results panel...

Comment: Thank you so much. The product team who decided that's how that feature works should have their eyes cut out

Comment: Horrible solution for a horrible product.

Answer (score 56):

I don't know in PgAdmin 4.3, but in 4.6 I found that way to re-arrange it.

First, right-click on somewhere to Add Panel -> Scratch Pad first to get a panel holder first (when clicking, notice the highlighted light blue space),

[image: screenshot_1]

then right-click the lower half space to add another panel -> Scratch Pad at the lower half space (when clicking, notice the highlighted light blue space),.

[image: screenshot_2]

After that, click on the tab and hold to drag and drop to where you want (when clicking, notice the highlighted light blue space).

[image: screenshot_3]

Comment: What I was missing is that holding the mouse button down over the name of the tab switches to move-this-tab mode.

Comment: Awesome, I can use the program again.

Comment: @JamieFristrom - this comment should be the answer!

Comment: Great that it helps!

Comment: As of version 4.25, I could not make it work. "Reset Layout" works though, but it is so annoying...

Comment: @greatvovan, I just tested and it still works on 4.25.

Comment: I just tested on pgAdmin 4 version 5.2, "File --> Reset Layout" is the last way to fix this. You can avoid accidentally move/drag a panel by going to "File --> Lock Layout --> Full Lock", so panels cannot be dragged/moved. You can choose "None" to leave it drag-able. Panels are still drag-able from its default docking position to other dock-able position while you still holding your dragging click. If you release the dragging click before docking at a new dock-able posting, then it seems that panel cannot dock at any position. When too messed up, go to "Reset Layout".

Answer (score 40):

I have pgadmin 4.15 and I found how to resolve this. On the upper left corner, click on **File** dropdown and then click on **Reset Layout**. It will ask to restart the application, click Ok.

Comment: This throws away all your current work. What a terrible UX.

Answer (score 17):

No this is not a bug, those panels are meant to be floatable so that user can arrange the view as per their convince.

But yes user should have the option to lock the layout, and I see feature request for locking the layout is already in the pgadmin4 list.
Hopefully, we will get it in the next future release.
Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3155

**------ UPDATE -----**

1. Now you can lock the layout in pgAdmin4 (File menu -> Lock layout) option
2. To reset the panels to default position (File manu -> Reset Layout) option

**------ UPDATE-2021 -----**

This issue has been fixed, can you please check with pgAdmin4 v5.5 which is released on 15-july-2021.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to return the floating panel to tiling ?; for me today the floating panel is unusable, I run the queries and it does not show results. Why floats do not have window options on the right side of their header? minimize, maximize, close, retiling? it would be very convenient

Comment: You can again drag & drop the panel to its original location.

Comment: Even by dragging and dropping to its original location, the window is still floating? How can I dock/pin after it is floating? I'm using pgAdmin 4.5 on mac.

Comment: It's still the case as of 4.5

Comment: Could the topic starter @glicuado set this as accepted answer? Reset Layout actually worked for me

Comment: Reset Layout throws away all your current work. It's not a fix, just another bug.

Comment: This is an infuriatingly simple missing feature. Why isn't there just a "re-dock" button on the floating window bar??

Answer (score 3):

reset is also available as an icon on the top right area of the UI

Comment: Particularly helpful for the mac version

Answer (score 2):

Long press with left mouse button on title permits you to reposition the panel in layout

Answer (score 1):

File dropdown >> Reset Layout (reload issue)
this will reload but the changes/query will be lost. Better to store the query somewhere else before resetting layout

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on 4.2.6, and as long as only one of the tabs has floated, I can click on the text "Data Output", and drag it onto the tab bar of the bottom panel. Note that you need to click the text, and not just anywhere in the panel's top bar, it acts as a kind of invisible tab.

If the other tabs (Explain, etc) have also floated I think you need a 'Scratch Pad' or Reset.

Then File, Lock Layout, Prevent Docking if this is never useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redock it in pgadmin 4, version 6.0 by dragging the floating window down to the bottom right of the screen. I drug it around down there until it started highlighting docking arrangements for it and it eventually shows a highlight for the original docking position and then you can let go and it'll dock. Not super exact instructions, but once you do it a couple times it's easy to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Running pgAdmin4 on Apple M1 Pro, Ventura > 13 click the half-circle with an arrow at the 12 o'clock position in the top right corner of the app. Hovering over the button reveals "Reset layout".

[reset layout is button in top right of picture and app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kiwL.png)